# Twitter embedded timeline widget

Tags: javascript, css, twitter

I went ahead and downloaded http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js

And the http://platform.twitter.com/embed/timeline.4d0955f67d15e8ef0601086ae2d5fcd0.default.css

Two files the embedded timeline widget uses.

All I'm trying to do is customize the css of the widget, and since twitter only gives you a few design options like link color and a dark/light theme, I thought it would be easier to download the files and modify them myself.

Only problem is, I'm having some difficulty trying to point the css file location inside the ***widgets.js*** to the copy on my webapp

A line inside ***widget.js***, locating the css file on twitters servers, its tied up with some variables that combine a prefixed ***platform.twitter.com/*** value or something

```
provide("tfw/assets",...{"default":"embed/timeline.4d0955f67d15e8ef0601086ae2d5fcd0.default.css",
```

I don't how much editing has to be done to ***widget.js*** but my guess its only a couple lines?

If anybody proficient in javascript wouldn't mind taking a look and telling me **"Not worth the effort"**, or **"It's simple, just change __ to __"**, let me know.

> ***widgets.js*** is the first hyperlink above

Answer (score 3):

(See my edit below for a better solution) This seemed to work for me and doesn't take much time to implement:

In widgets.js, find

```
function Z(a,b,c)
```

Change this in function Z:

```
d.href=twttr.widgets.config.assetUrl()+"/"+b
```

to something like this:

```
d.href=b
```

The assetUrl just gets the base URL of the file (eg. a CSS file), which is at a domain Twitter owns. b will be the paths you specify throughout the JS (such as embed/timeline.4d0955f67d15e8ef0601086ae2d5fcd0.default.css ). Upload all the CSS (like timeline.xyz.default.css) to where you want it, then you can customize those files and keep them on your own server. You can't modify the CSS by simply adding rules to a CSS file on your server, since the Twitter feed is in an iframe from a different domain. Modifying CSS in iframes with this type of source (ie. not from your own domain) is not allowed, to prevent hijacking-type problems, but if the iframe refers to a CSS on your own server then you can modify things.

There may be some other things you might want to check out to make sure you have all the required files.  You should also get sprite.png which is referred to in the Twitter CSS file. I was able to customize the CSS this way and it worked fine.

**Edit:**

I had problems with the above solution in IE7/6 and Chrome in Jelly Bean so found a better solution that lets you inject your own custom CSS file into the iframe while sticking with all of Twitter's CSS at their own domain.  From a fresh widgets.js I went and added the following:

```
;d=c.createElement("link"),
d.id="custom-css-1",
d.rel="stylesheet",
d.type="text/css",
d.href="http://mydomain.com/css/timeline.custom.css";
c.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(d);
```

immediately after

```
c.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(d)
```

on the line in widgets.js starting with

```
provide("tfw/widget/timeline"
```

(again in function Z) This seems to work much better, and all you need is a copy of widgets.js at http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js.

Comment: I tried this method and I think it is brilliant, however, I cannot get it to work. After performing your edits to a clean JS file, I get a seemingly blank page. However on closer inspection I see that it is generating the iframe and both the twitter and custom css are attached and the script seem to run, but with no real output. The page is throwing no errors and I am baffled. Stepping through the calls, it is definitely the edited line that breaks it Any insight? The page is at: (subsitute www. where appropriate of course) doubleu doubleu doubleu dot manatee.k12.fl.us/sites/title1/edlin

Comment: I figured out what it was that fixed the problem where the Twitter feed was blank, which is hopefully a fix for your problem. The changes I made above (by recreating the element rather than just reusing the one created in the original widgets.js file) fixed it.  It was only happening when the custom CSS file had an incorrect path. Have you checked to make sure your path to your custom CSS is accessible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if I download wigdet.js and custom.css then widget does not pick up
data-chrome="transparent"

I downloaded 
http://platform.twitter.com/embed/timeline.4d0955f67d15e8ef0601086ae2d5fcd0.default.css

renamed it timeline.custom.css

Changed in wigdet.js link to my css

```
function b(e,t,n){
            var r;
            n=n||document;
            if(n.getElementById(e))return;
            r=n.createElement("link"),
            r.id=e,r.rel="stylesheet",
            r.type="text/css",
            r.href= "../css/timeline.custom.css",
            n.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(r)
        }
```

Is link to css correct? Or twitter uses the newest version of css?
http://platform.twitter.com/embed/timeline.4d0955f67d15e8ef0601086ae2d5fcd0.default.css

How to make widget to pickup the data-chrome="transparent"

I used widget script

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"    
data-dnt="true"  
href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23My_hush"                          
data-tweet-limit="1"
data-theme="dark" 
data-screen-name="some_name"                        
data-chrome="noscrollbar noheader transparent noborders nofooter"                        
      data-widget-id="My_id">
      Tweets about "#My_hush"</a>
```