# How to customize the widgets generated by the Twitter Configuration?

Tags: css, widget, customization

I would like to know how to customize the widgets generated by the Twitter Configuration (https://twitter.com/settings/widgets). I would like to change the CSS (alignment, size, paddings,etc...), is it possible?

Best regards,
Andreza

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306588/twitter-embedded-timeline-widget/12739369

Answer (score 0):

Currently not.

Quote from https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines

> **Customization Options**
>
> Embedded timelines are available in light and dark themes for
>   customization. The light theme is for pages that use a white or light
>   colored background and follows the twitter.com aesthetic, while the
>   dark theme is for pages that use a black or dark color background and
>   looks more like Tweetdeck.
>
> As with your twitter.com profile, you may choose a custom link color
>   for your embedded timelines so that the content matches the links of
>   your website and feels integrated into the color palette of your site.
>
> No other customization options are available at this time.